# ChangeNotifier wrap class around each instance of a model

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I have an application where I display a list of cards that represent a model (Let's say a Person). These are stateless widgets as they cannot be changed directly. These instances are obtained from an API and, since the amount of items is large, I am using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to keep them from reloading and triggering more API calls.

When clicked, these cards lead to the Person's page where there we can edit some information on them. Using a `StatefullWidget` here with `setState` takes care of all issues related to the page. However, when I pop the individual page the card that was clicked does not reflect the changes made.

I was thinking of writing a `ChangeNotifier` wrapper for each Person but from what I've read this is a bad idea. Using more powerful state management tools like BLoC or Redux seems like overkill too. How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
ontap: () async {
  
 await Navigator.push ....);
 
 ref
}
```